# on click link (More) Show more table field data ..??

Tags: php, mysql

There is large number of column in my database. I fetch all this on my webpage.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeeAW.jpg) Is that any way to show  4 to 5 column with MORE link. On click remaining wiil be display on the same page same table raw wise

Comment: Use ajax and append a new column to your current table. Try yourself first and update your question if you get and problem.

Comment: Do you want to load particular row, on click MORE button, or load all rows?

Comment: without ajax, you can also do  hide() the some column

Comment: Check this to append rows/columns : http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/R2Her/

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the best solution for it. Or You can do that by jQuery `hide()` and `show()` function. Hide all after 4/5 column and append a button which will show rest of the column when clicked.
check it - https://jsfiddle.net/iqbalbary/sjnybu05/

Comment: Yes Particular row..@ harish sharma